# Prove that the following probability density is symmetric about zero.

Tags: probability-distributions

This problem is question number 25 in John A. Rice's *Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis* (3rd ed.).

> Let $X$ have the density $f$, and let $Y=X$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and $Y=-X$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.  Show that the density of $Y$ is symmetric about zero $-$ that is, $f_Y(y) = f_Y(-y)$.

What I've done is the following:

1. We are given that $Y=X$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and $Y=-X$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ so this means $f_{Y|X}(x|x) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f_{Y|X}(-x|x) = \frac{1}{2}$; that is, conditional under $X$, $Y$ is discrete uniform.
2. By the multiplication law, $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x)$.  Hence, $f_{X,Y}(x,x) = \frac{1}{2}f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,-x) = \frac{1}{2}f_{X}(x)$.  Similarly, $f_{X,Y}(-x,-x) = \frac{1}{2}f_{X}(-x)$ and $f_{X,Y}(-x,x) = \frac{1}{2}f_{X}(-x)$.  This shows that the density of $Y$ is symmetric about 0.

...But I'm not too sure.  First, is the proof correct?  Second, if it is, does this mean that the joint density function is over the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$?

Answer (score 1):

$$f_Y(y)=\tfrac12f_X(y)+\tfrac12f_X(-y)=f_Y(-y)$$

Comment: So you just used the law of total probability, right?